# nmap taking ages

Tags: nmap

I am using Try Hack Me to attempt to learn but they tell me to run `nmap -A -p-` and it is taking over an hour for a scan.

I am really new to this and want to know is there a faster way to perform a scan that shows open ports and os version?

Comment: `man nmap` has a ton of options. `-T` is what you're looking for.

Comment: It's always a good idea to add the full command you are running to your question. There's no way to know how big a network you are scanning, for example.

Comment: Expecting nmap to do fingerprinting and complaining about how long it takes is not logical.

Comment: Don't just follow instructions blindly from a website, find out what nmap -A -p xxxxx does before you try it.

Comment: fingerprinting is relatively fast, probing all ports most of which are dropping connections is quite slow.

Answer (score 0):

As commenter @JeremyBoden wrote, "don't just follow instructions blindly from a website, find out what `nmap -A -p xxxxx` does before you try it".

The `-A` flag selects an Aggressive scan.  This option is equivalent to `-O -sV -sC --traceroute`.

The `-p-` option scans all ports from 1 to 65535, as opposed to the Nmap default which scans only the most common ports.  So it's normal that the command takes a long time.

You can run a faster scan by using the option `-T4` or `-T5`, which use optimized parallelization.  Please read the Nmap manual beforehand as these options are meant for high bandwidth networks. The Nmap default is `-T3`.